# Service sharing

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service which provides current location of the device. Several activities in my app can call this service at the same time. If I call stopService() in an activity, can it make the service running in different activity stop? I have read Android document but still confused about that. Please make it clear for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one instance of the service. You can call startService() from multiple activities, but it will have only one instance. As soon as any of the activities calls stopService() it will be stopped for all activities.